# How to draw bitmap on cube side with sceneform?

Tags: android, sceneform

I'm using sceneform to draw my model (cube with round corners). I would like to draw an image on one side only.
Currently I load image into texture and create material with that texture and texture is drawn on whole cube.
My code:

```
val texture = Texture.builder()
.setSource { assets.open("picture.png") }
.build()
.get()

val materialFuture = MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithTexture(this, texture)

ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this, uri)
                .build()
                .thenAcceptBoth(materialFuture) { model, material ->
                    model.material = material
                    scene.addChild(model)
                }
```

I assume that I have to create some material which will describe texture drawing.

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: Nope, I did not